# Webscraping using BeautifulSoup: Different page content from same URL

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to build a program that analyses listings on a popular apartment renting website in Switzerland. The end goal is to gather key information (area, price etc.) of all listings in a certain area for further analysis.

The program is built of 2 parts; the first creates a list of all URLs of listings, the second goes to each of these URLs and puts the key information into a dict.

I seemed to get wrong information though, e.g. the program would say a listing has 6.5 rooms even though when I check the URL manually it only says 3.5. After some trial and error I realized that the same URL leads to 2 different pages, please see the pictures attached (sorry for the German, but you can compare the numbers ;)

How can the page content differ between 2 pages with the same URL? The images of the apartments are even the same, so one of the 2 must be wrong.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhKH7.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/krkLv.jpg)